# Fetch.Lazy when you retrieve a List and Fetch.Eager when you return one Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've always thought what could've been the best way to deal with this problem in Spring/Hibernate. Imagine we have an Entity like House:

```
public class House {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String address;
    List<Person> people;
}
```

Where `Person` is another Entity. Now, if we want to show a list of every house that is stored, we just want some details, id, name and address, we don't want the entire data to be fetched because we are not showing the people in the list.
When we enter a detail view, however, we are interested in showing the people as well.

What's the best way to fetch the people just when you want them, taking care of the LazyInitializationException as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of options. I just highlight the one I use:

**JOIN FETCH**

If you need the people eager loaded you can create a query like:

```
select h from House h fetch join people p
```

If you think this will produce to many queries go for entity graphs.

**ENTITY GRAPH**

Definition:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.House.people", 
      attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("people"))
public class House {
```

Usage with Spring Data JPA:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "graph.House.people", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
List<House> findById(Long id);
```

But there are more. Please read: https://thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/

Comment: The only bad point that I see to your solution is that I would need to write more queries for when I want to fetch everything. It would be nice to have some shortcuts in jpa query names, just like in findById(), something like findByIdFetchPeople.

Comment: I added a solution with Entity Graph that reduces the amount of queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Entity graph in the repository. Just use @EntityGraph to define an ad-hoc entity graph on your method.

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"people"})
List<House> findAll();
```

Here, you can define attributes which you want to fetch as `attributePaths`.
Call this when you want to show people otherwise call `findAll()`.

And you can use lazy fetching for `people` also, whenever you want `people` just call the getter of it then JPA will automatically fetch `people` in another query.